# Match any number of digits NOT followed by

Tags: search, regular-expression, substitute

I want to search for:

> From start of the line, any number of white spaces followed by any
>   number of digits NOT followed by a dot.

And replace it with all that was searched and a dot. This is just to introduce a dot in a simple numbered list when forgotten.

So, I went:

```
:%s/^\(\s*\d\+\)\.\@!/\1\.
```

This breaks down if there is a two digit number with a dot following it.

For example:

- This `1 Some text` becomes this `1. Some text` as expected.
- But, this `10. Some text` becomes `1.0. Some text` instead staying unchanged.

Comment: this works for me with a 7.4.1689 and 8.0.586 What version have you been using?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I am using vim 8.0 and it works like I have explained in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, what you need is `\>` at the end of the regular expression like so:

```
:%s/^\(\s*\d\+\)\.\@!\>/\1\.
```

Or even better:

```
:%s/^\s*\d\+\.\@!\>\zs/.
```

**Note:** A `.` in the replacement part of the `:substitute` command is literal so you can remove the leading `\`. [`:help sub-replace-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub%2dreplace%2dspecial) describes what needs to be escaped and its meaning.

But if you want to make it work for:

```
10.10 something
10.10.10 something
10.10.10.10 something
```

and so on, you'll need a regular expression that's similar to yours:

```
:%s/^\s*[0-9.]*\d\.\@!\>\zs/.
```

### Explanation

- `^\s*` Whitespaces at the beginning of the line.
- `[0-9.]*` Digits and literal dots that match the correct part of the string, i.e., the `10.1`, `10.10.1` and `10.10.10.1` in the previous example.
- `\d\.\@!` The digit that requires a dot after it.
- `\>` The previous digit at the end of a word (see [`:help /\>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%3e)).
- `\zs\` If the previous regular expression matches,  ignore it and match what follows, i.e., just after the end of the word and before the whitespace in the previous example (see [`:help /\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5czs)).

Comment: nice explanation and told me what was wrong with my solution! \>!!

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised how complicated this can be done (-;

Your requirement can be met with a simple

```
:%s/^\s*\d\+\zs\.*/./
```

Explanation:

`^`       Lines starting with
`\s*`   any number of blanks
`\d\+` followed by one or more digits
`\zs`   here starts the pattern that will get replaced
`\.*`   any number of dots (you could also do `\.\?`) gets replaced
`/./`   by a single dot

So the trick is to always put a dot behind the number. If there already is a dot, it gets replaced by a new one.

Comment: This works perfectly. I almost understand how. It replaces all "Start Space Digits Character" sequence with "Start Space Digits Dot". But I am not clear about the exact syntax used. If you could please explain, that would be great

Comment: You are using things like `\@!` I never used so I thought you don't need an explanation. (-: Now I added one.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly your question what you want is this:

```
:%s/\s*\d\+\([0-9\.]\)\@!/\0.
```

You need to group the digits and the dot in the group you're excluding with `\@!` other wise the match stops before the `0` in `10` and the dot is inserted whereas it shouldn't.

With this command you transform this:

```
1 Foo
10 Bar
10. Bar
    1 Foo
    10 Bar
    10. Bar
```

in this:

```
1. Foo
10. Bar
10. Bar
    1. Foo
    10. Bar
    10. Bar
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a zero-width match to specify *not* to include the dots, you could set the end of the match and then specify what *is* included in the "wrong" lines. That is, if the digits are followed by space or end-of-line, one should add a dot:

```
:%s/^\s*\d\+\ze\(\s\|$\)/\0.
```

Here `\ze` sets the end of the match, and the group matches either a space or the end-of-line.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
%s/^\(\s*\d\+\)\(\.\?\d\+\)\?\.\?\(\s\)/\1\2.\3/g
```

- the first group is any number of "empty" characters followed by one or more digits;
- the second group is zero or one point followed by one ore more digits, but this group can appear one or more times;
- the third group is any number of "empty" characters at the end (so they can be preserved);

It transforms this:

```
  1. abobora
  10. abobora
  1 abobora
  10 abobora
  10.5 abobora

1 Foo
10 Bar
10. Bar
    1 Foo
    10 Bar
    10. Bar
```

into this:

```
  1. abobora
  10. abobora
  1. abobora
  10. abobora
  10.5. abobora

1. Foo
10. Bar
10. Bar
    1. Foo
    10. Bar
    10. Bar
```

It would be easier to understand without all those escape characters:

```
    %s/^(\s*\d+)(\.?\d+)?\.?(\s)/\1\2.\3/g
```

But without them it wouldn't work :)

Comment: You can use `\v` to turn on `very magic` magic which would make your substitution work, `:%s/\v^(\s*\d+)(\.?\d+)?\.?(\s)/\1\2.\3/`. However we can do even better by using `\zs` to get rid of all the capture groups, `%s/\v^\s*\d+(\.?\d+)?\zs\.?/./`