# What is an atom?

Tags: regular-expression, terminology

I have been looking through many resources but cannot seem to find the definition of an atom. In the website link http://vimregex.com/, how does an atom defer from a character in regex?

```
\{-}
matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible
```

and

```
\+
matches 1 or more of the preceding characters...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pattern is made up of atoms, from [`:help /atom`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fatom):

```
An atom can be one of a long list of items.  Many atoms match one
character in the text.  It is often an ordinary character or a character
class.  Braces can be used to make a pattern into an atom.
```

- *An atom can be one of a long list of items*, refer to  [`:help /ordinary-atom`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fordinary%2datom) and [`:help pattern-atoms`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern%2datoms) to see the *long list of items*. For example, `$` (end-of-line) and `^` (start-of-line) don't match any character but rather they describe a characteristic of the pattern. See [`:help /zero-width`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fzero%2dwidth)
- *Many atoms match one character in the text*. That's why atom and character are used interchangeably, for example `a` matches a literal `a`, `[0-9a-z]` matches one character of the range, `\$` and `\^` match a literal `$` and `^` respectively.
- *Parentheses can be used to make a pattern into an atom*, like `\(foo\)` in:

  ```
  \(foo\)\?bar
  ```

  In this case, the atom `\(foo\)` matches three characters or atoms: `f`, `o` and `o` .

You could find some examples [in this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13106/6698).

Comment: Ok, Now I get it. _An atom can be one of a long list of items._ So, as the OP asked, what is an atom? BTW, in the 3rd bullet I don't see any _braces_, so it makes even less sense.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver the list is everything that's in [`:h /ordinary-atom`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fordinary-atom), all the way upto `5. Multi items`.

Comment: Now I actually _do_ get it. An atom the smallest _thing_, along with its modifiers, in the pattern which can match something in the string. The whole pattern is made from a collection of atoms. `:h /ordinary-atom` helped, The quote from `:help /atom` merely reinforced the question without answering it.